# How to download data from Firebase Realtime Database to device storage

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, android-download-manager

I have a recyclerview that displays images from my Firebase Realtime database storage. I've attached a button to the recyclerview.

[image: My app layout]

When users click the download button. I want my app to download that specific image from Firebase into their devices storage. How would I go about this? I've never downloaded from Firebase before, so I could really use some help.

Comment: What have you tried to achieve that in code?

Comment: I've tried watching tutorials on YouTube, but they were all for the Firestore Storeage and the code for that does not work for me because all of my data is in Realtime database. I tried reading the official Firebase documentation as well, but it seems to a single link download. I have data in a recyclerview and this code just isn't working